# Is it possible to stop Generating stubs for Ruby core in Aptana

Tags: ruby, aptana

I'm wondering if it is possible to stop this Aptana feature:

"Generating stubs for Ruby core" because my Eclipse hangs on 0% for couple of hours and sometime freezes.

I use Ruby but don't use Ruby on rails.

Best regards!

my conf: Eclipse 3.5.1 + Aptana 3.0.7 (as a plugin), Windows 7 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

If you are using just the ruby then  [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) would be a good tool like Mac's Textmate. Its a tiny software & so simple to use, you will be amazed!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug. I've opened a ticket for this, specifically to fix it so that you can attempt to cancel the operation and that it gives finer-grained progress so that if it does hang we can get better details on what exact step and/or file it's choking on). http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4168